# convert timezone in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am creating web app using angularjs. I want to convert the timezone according to different countries.here is my date format:

```
2016-02-01T15:45:45Z
```

I know there is filter but this does not works for me:

```
{{ clock | date: 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : '+0900' }}
```

Here is my code:

```
 <td>{{informationData.instantiated | date: 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : '+0900'}}</td>
```

Comment: It works for me {{ '2016-02-01T15:45:45Z' | date: 'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : '+0900' }}  Provide your plunkr url.

Comment: how can format T and Z  in datetime ???

Comment: Here is the plunkr url http://run.plnkr.co/beJiwqQib2VcfIXz/

Comment: your plunker is not working..

Comment: I tried this and worked for me, try this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/eo4hn2mv/

Comment: @Karan, Here is the link which is working https://embed.plnkr.co/PjxgVFeBl80MH0gBrvnX/.. Not sure why that was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use Moment.js to convert date and time for any timezone

ex: `moment().format('LLL');  //Februrary 2, 2016 12:41`

Answer (score 0):

Load moment.js library than

convert your datetime

user below code in your javascript file

```
var myDateTime = 2016-02-01T15:45:45Z;

moment(myDateTime).format('MMM d, YYYY H:mm:ss');
```

you will get output like this:

```
Feb 1, 2016 21:15:45
```